# How can I implement drawing line with multiple points on wpf canvas?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, drawing

I am using .NET MVC silverlight 4. I am trying to use MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseMove and MouseLeftButtonUp events. I am confused with what to use between line, polyline or path?

Answer (score 2):

Use Line if you want straight lines between two points.

Use PolyLine if you want multiple straight, connecting lines between multiple points

Use Path if you want curved lines.

[See the MSDN for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)